# I am trying to pass modal button to ajax search result table in laravel

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, laravel

I have to use ajax to search a table in my project but I have no idea how I can make the modal button work in the search result table. Do note that the modal button works fine on the orignal table. Just trying to make it work on the search result.

Here is my Controller code.

```
 public function search_student(Request $request){
    $output="";


    $searchStudent=User::where('name','LIKE', '%'.$request->searchstud.'%')->
    orWhere('lastname','LIKE', '%'.$request->searchstud.'%')->
    orWhere('class','LIKE', $request->searchstud)->get();


    foreach ($searchStudent as $key => $searchStudent)

    {
        $url= asset('upload/studentphoto/'.$searchStudent->image);
        $printicon= url('view-student-result', $searchStudent->admission_num);
        //$editmodal= url('student.update', $searchStudent->id);

            $output.=
            '<tr>
            <td>'. $key + 1 .'</td>

            <td>'.
            '<img src="'. $url .'" border-radius="15px" width="60px" height="50px" alt="">'
            .'</td>

            <td>'.$searchStudent->name.'</td>
            <td>'.$searchStudent->lastname.'</td>
            <td>'.$searchStudent->admission_num.'</td>
            <td>'.$searchStudent->class.'</td>
            <td>'.$searchStudent->date_of_birth.'</td>
            <td>'.$searchStudent->gender.'</td>
            <td>'.$searchStudent->category.'</td>
            <td>
            '.' <a href="'. $printicon .'"><i class="fas fa-print"></i>'.'</a>'.'
            </td>
            <td>
            '.' <a href=""> <i class="fas fa-edit">This is where the modal button is.</i>'.'</a>'.'

            </td>


            </tr>';
    }

    return response($output);

}
```

Here is my .blade file with the modal code

```
<a href="" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#exampleModa3{{ $studentDatas->id }}"><i class="fas fa-edit"></i></a>
                                <!--Modal class for Edit Button-->
                                    <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModa3{{ $studentDatas->id }}" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabe3" aria-hidden="true">
                                        <div class="modal-dialog">
                                            <div class="modal-content">
                                                <div class="modal-header">
                                                    <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Edit Student's Profile</h5>
                                                    <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
                                                </div>
                                              
                                                <div class="modal-footer">
                                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
```

Here is my Ajax code in the .blad file.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
                $('#search_student').on('keyup', function()

                {
                    $value=$(this).val();
                    if ($value){
                        $('.allstudents').hide();
                        $('.searchstudent').show();

                    }else{
                        $('.allstudents').show();
                        $('.searchstudent').hide();
                    }

                    $.ajax({
                        type:"get",
                        url:"{{ URL::to('search-student') }}",
                        data:{'searchstud':$value},

                        success:function(data)
                        {
                            console.log(data);
                            $('#Content').html(data);
                        }

                    });

                })

            </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are setting student ID in each modal, either make one universal modal or render the modal also on ajax call. If u want the work done with your own method, append the modal code also to $output and change {{ $studentDatas->id }} to $searchStudent->id
To append modal code on output , you can do like

```
.' <a href=""> <i class="fas fa-edit">This is where the modal button is.</i>'.'</a>'.'

        </td>


        </tr>';
$output.= '<a href="" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#exampleModa3'.$searchStudent->id.'"><i class="fas fa-edit"></i></a>'
                            .'<!--Modal class for Edit Button-->'
                                .'<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModa3'.$searchStudent->id.'" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabe3" aria-hidden="true">'
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. How can I append the modal code to $output?

Comment: I have edited answer for you

Comment: Thanks so much, when I try this, the button responded with faded black screen like the modal was goin to open but it didnt. I wil like to ask, will this `<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModa3'.$searchStudent->id.'" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabe3" aria-hidden="true">'` replace the div tag of the modal button in the .blade

Comment: No, it will create modal for each of your student data. By the way it is not the right method when it comes to code optimization . for that you can write single dynamic modal and pass the data from individual student to the modal.